# Javascript variable "not cleared" on Ajax page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running a CRUD app working with php/js which relies on an ajax page change. Inside the "add view", there's a simple table and a button that insert a new row each time you click it.

On the first load, when I click on the button, it adds one row, I save and it loads the list view (thanks to an ajax call). Then, when I access a second time to the "add view" and click on the button supposed to add one row, it adds two rows and so on after each page load.

Here my js code supposed to add one row to my table:

```
$('body').on('click', '#delivery_grid_add_row', function(){
   var markup = '';
   markup+= '<tr>';
   markup+= '<td>';
   markup += 'hello world';
   markup+= '</td>';
   markup+= '</tr>';
   $('tbody').append(markup);
});
```

I know my explanation isn't very clear since english isn't my native language but feel free to let me know if you want further information.

Comment: Please share also you HTML code

Comment: Please include a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .html not .append this may solve your problem. Append always add elements after previous element so its holding your previous html. Instead of using append use html which will replace your previous html

```
$('body').on('click', '#delivery_grid_add_row', function(){
   var markup =  $('tbody').html();
   markup+= '<tr>';
   markup+= '<td>';
   markup += 'hello world';``
   markup+= '</td>';
   markup+= '</tr>';
   $('tbody').html(markup);
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case... with this code you will always add the same line

Comment: Yes, i would like to add another row not replace it. Should I "clear" the append method after each time maybe ?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my code hopefully this will add single row every time you click

Comment: Great I'll be using your solution.

Comment: sometimes append gives you some trouble. Try to avoid it as much as possible. Things I have done append would do the same thing apparently.